# Dragging a shape in kinetic js is also moving an unrelated shape

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs

I've got a line that is drawn from one point to another. I add circles to the ends of the line that allows the line to be moved.

However, when I move the circle, and the line updates, another line is somehow updating its own points.

Before (movement should only be happening on right hand side of screen):
[image: before]

After:
[image: after]

Here is the fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/Robodude/s86xc/1/

(For some reason the lines aren't being drawn reliably in chrome on js fiddle... it works fine locally, but online I can only get them to show on FF)

Basic instructions: In the left grid, click on a circle. Click on a second circle. A line between the points should be drawn. Click the 'Copy Q to A' button and the line should be drawn in the right frame with circle end points that can be dragged around.

On the right side, the this is whats going on:

1) Lines get drawn in right side group.

2) Circles get drawn at the ends of the lines.

3) Circles are given references to all the lines that start/end at their center

4) When dragged, the circles update the lines it has references for.

As far as I can tell, the circles do not have references to the lines in the left side panel.

Left side lines have the name "line" and right side lines (that the circle has references for) have the name "line2"

This is how I'm giving the circles references to the lines. If the circle at the x,y coord already exists, push the line to it's connectedLines property

```
var circleTest = circleGroup.get("." + point.x + ", " + point.y)[0];
if (circleTest == null) {
    var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
        name: (point.x) + ", " + (point.y),
        x: point.x,
        y: point.y,
        radius: answer ? 15 : 10,
        stroke: "rgba(0,0,0,1)",
        strokeWidth: "3",
        fill: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)",
        connectedLines: [line],
        draggable: answer ? false: true,
        oldX: point.x,
        oldY: point.y,
        dragBoundFunc: answer ? null : function (pos) {
            var x = pos.x;
            var y = pos.y;

            var newPos = { x: x - offset.x, y: y - offset.y };

            updateAttachedLines(newPos, this);

            return {
                x: x,
                y: y
            }
        }
    });

    circle.on("click", function () {
        console.log(this.attrs.connectedLines);
    });

    circleGroup.add(circle);
}
else {
    circleTest.attrs.connectedLines.push(line);
}
```

This is what updateAttachedLines looks like:

```
function updateAttachedLines(pos, circle)
{
    var x = pos.x;
    var y = pos.y;
    var ox = circle.attrs.oldX;
    var oy = circle.attrs.oldY;

    var cls = circle.attrs.connectedLines;

    for (var i = 0; i < cls.length; i++) {
        var cl = cls[i];
        console.log(cl.attrs.name);
        var points = cl.getPoints();

        var newPoints = [];
        for (var n = 0; n < points.length; n++) {
            var point = points[n];

            if ((point.x == ox) && (point.y == oy)) {
                point.x = x;
                point.y = y;
            }

            newPoints.push(point);
        }

        cl.setPoints(newPoints);
    }

    circle.parent.parent.draw();

    circle.attrs.oldX = x;
    circle.attrs.oldY = y;
}
```

So why does movement in the right hand side line, affect the left hand side line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you create a new `Kinetic.Line` object when you `buildLines` for the `answerGroup`, you don't **copy** the points of the original line and rather pass the reference.

Which means that, on changing the points of the line in the `answerGroup`, you end up also changing the points of the original line in the `lineGroup`.

Now, following this intuition, the general idea would be to copy the points' array with `line.points.slice()` when you create a new `Kinetic.Line` in `buildLines`. This would actually work if `line.points` was always an array of numbers, but it can be of three types:

```
points: [Number, Number, Number, ...]
or
points: [Array, Array, Array, ...]
or
points: [Object, Object, Object, ...]
```

So, now it should be ensured that when a new line is made for the answer group, the points it gets from the original line are all copies and not references. One way to achieve this would be to use `map` on `line.points`.

Let the callback be:

```
var _copyPts = function(e, i, a) {
    if(e instanceof Array) {
        return e.slice();
    }
    else if(e instanceof Object) {
        var r = {};
        for(var k in e) {
            if(e.hasOwnProperty(k)) r[k] = e[k];
        }
        return r;
    }

    return e;
};
```

And, the change in `buildLines` be:

```
...
var lineShape = new Kinetic.Line({
    id: "l" + i,
    name: "line2",
    stroke: answer ? "rgba(000,000,000,1)" : line.color,
    strokeWidth: answer ? 8 : 5,
    points: line.points.map(_copyPts),     //<--- change here
    dashArray: answer ? [10, 5] : null
});
...
```

Here's a [**working version**](http://jsfiddle.net/v39C4/).

Comment: +1 Nice catch!  Reminds me of the good old/bad old days of Silverlight programming where some key collections unexpectedly didn't have a clone method.

Comment: Thank you very much - it works great. I'm not too familiar with .map so I'll look into that later today :)